# how to login into unix system and run script through jenkins in windows

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I have install jenkins in windows system but I have to run script which is on unix server. to run that script i have to first login into unix box then run the script. Any one ca help in it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use Execute shell script on remote host using ssh in Add BUILD.